# Fields to set in GA4 configuration that set to fire multiple times

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have some questions about GA4 configuration tag. My application is an SPA. I need to track some info for each tags fired. To avoid adding the same parameters in all tags, I tried to add them in GA4 configuration parameters. I set the GA4 configuration to fired for each history change (So it will fired everytime user change their path).
[image: My GA4 configuration tag]

My question are the following:

1. Is there any cons on set the configuration tag to fire multiple times (instead of once on page load)?
2. Right now, the parameters in `user properties` works fine, but parameters in `fields to set` (Module and Menu) is not received in GA debug view (although it is seems to sent in GTM preview)

[image: GTM Preview]
[image: GA Debug view - I expect there will be module and menu there]